# Vue - Keep default Router-View alive when change another named view

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

**Situation:**

I use, beside of the default route-view, a named route-view. I want to keep the DEFAULT route-view alive when I call the ArticleComponent, but as you can see, you can call the ArticleComponent from 2 different routes/components. You can find a fiddle link under the code snippet.

**What I want to do:**

If I open the ArticleComponent from ListingComponent, then ListingComponent should stay alive in the default route-view.

If I call the ArticleComponent from the FeedComponent, then the FeedComponent should stay alive in the default route-view.

**My code:**

```js
const HomeComponent = {
    template: '<h4>Home</h4>'
};

const FeedComponent = {
    template: `<div>
    <h4>FeedComponent</h4>
    <router-link to="/article/1">Article 1</router-link> -
    <router-link to="/article/2">Article 2</router-link>
  </div>`
};

const ListingComponent = {
    template: `<div>
    <h4>ListingComponent</h4>
    <router-link to="/article/1">Article 1</router-link> -
    <router-link to="/article/2">Article 2</router-link> -
    <router-link to="/article/3">Article 3</router-link>
  </div>`
};

const ArticleComponent = {
    template: `<h4>Article {{ $route.params.id }}</h4>`
};

const routes = [
    {
    path: '/',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/feed',
    component: FeedComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/listing',
    component: ListingComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/article/:id?',
    components: { 
      default: FeedComponent, // <--- dynamically
      secondary: ArticleComponent
    }
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

**Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/kvnvooo/b589uvLt/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to alter default component dynamically...

```js
{
    path: '/article/:id?',
    components: {
      default: FeedComponent,
      secondary: ArticleComponent
    },
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if(from.fullPath === '/listing') {
        to.matched[0].components.default = ListingComponent
      } else if(from.fullPath === '/feed') {
        to.matched[0].components.default = FeedComponent
      }
      next();
    }
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dhmLby6f/7/